# Git: Is there a way to re-merge two commits on the same branch (FF) to a new branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm working on a group project, and after making some changes and pushing to origin (call this commit `A`), another person seems to have force pushed their changes, thereby reverting my commits (call this commit `B`).

Before I push, we have something like this:

```
A (master)
|  B (their-master)
|  |
| /
Z (origin/master)
```

After I push, we get

```
   B (their-master)
   |
A (origin/master, master)
| /
Z
```

They pull my commit, revert it and push

```
B (origin/master, their-master)
|
A (master)
|
Z
```

I unknowingly pull and end up with

```
B (origin/master, master, their-master)
|
A
|
Z
```

I would like to make a new branch at `A` (e.g. "re-merge"), fetch `B` to the new branch to manually resolve merge conflicts. Then merge it back into master so we can keep changes by other people and get around the force commits.

```
                                     D (origin/master, master, re-merge)
   C (re-merge)                      | \
   |                                 |  C
B (origin/master, master)    -->     B  |
| /                                  | /
A                                    A
|                                    |
Z                                    Z
```

Is there a way to do this without making the branch at `A` and manually diffing files to find what I want to keep? This would force me to abandon the master branch since the forced changes in `B` seem to be considered fast-forwarding from `A` now. Besides other people working on unrelated things are also committing to master.

Thanks.

Comment: What you have drawn (with `B` pointing back to `A` as its parent) is not a force-push.  If your recent changes are there in commit `A`, it sounds more like your collaborator decided to *revert* your work (undo it all) and then perhaps make additional changes and push the result as the single commit `B`.  In the rest of your text, though, you make it sound like commit `A` is a common base commit, you have a now-hidden commit `A2`, and commit `B` is the collaborator's commit; that could indeed result from a forced push.  But you will still have your commit in your repo; you can merge or rebase.

Comment: Aha, I knew I was a bit unclear (and don't really know what I'm talking about).

There is a common base commit  `Z` that is what we were working from individually, but I committed and pushed `A` before `B` was pushed. You are probably right that they reverted my commit in their pull/merge/whatever and pushed that. Since I pulled `B` from the server, I don't see how I can rebase, or is it possible to rebase a parent onto a child (since `B` in my tree is formally a child of `A`)?

Comment: If they've reverted your work, you have to re-apply it.  This is relatively easy: just use `git cherry-pick`.  See answer below based on revised graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what they did was save their versions of some file(s) (possibly all of the files in question), then after rebasing their work on your commit, copy their saved version of the files, thus reverting your own work (without using an actual `git revert`, but still totally failing the idea of sharing work :-) ).

You're correct that you can't just merge, since your commit `A` is already included in the current commit's ancestry.

It's easy to recover without merge, though.  What you want is to have git see what you did between commit `Z` and commit `A`:

```
$ git diff <rev-id-for-Z> <rev-id-for-A>
```

or, since your `HEAD` commit is `B` so that `HEAD~1` (aka `B~1` `B^` aka `HEAD^` etc) is `A`, and `HEAD~2` is `Z`:

```
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1
```

and then take that diff—well, maybe part of that diff; we'll try that if needed—and apply it to the current work tree and make a new commit from the result:

```
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 | git apply && git commit
```

There is a command that does all this for you: `git cherry-pick`.  You point `cherry-pick` to a particular commit and it diffs that commit against its predecessor, applies the resulting diff to your current work-tree (if it can), and commits the result with a commit message saying that this is a cherry-pick of that other commit.

If you would like a different commit message, you can either `git commit --amend` the result, or, using the `-n` or `--no-commit` option, tell cherry-pick not to make the commit (this also allows the work tree to have other changes already).

If the cherry-pick does not go cleanly—for instance if manual merging is required—you will again have to do some cleanup work.  Alternatively, you can run the `git diff ... | git apply` yourself, in which case you can limit the set of files diff-ed:

```
$ git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 -- path1 path2 | git apply
```

and so on.

(Note, incidentally, that unlike diff-and-apply, `cherry-pick` has direct access to the commit graph.  It can therefore do merge type work automatically, making it smarter than just applying a patch.  The diff text leaves enough clues for `apply` to use its `-3` option to do the same but you must direct `apply` to do that.  Last, as just a side note, when you find yourself doing a `git diff` of some commit's parent vs that commit, that's just the diff part of `git show`, so as long as whatever you're doing tolerates "leading text", you can in fact just use `git show` on the target commit, rather than an explicit diff of its parent vs itself.  But that's not as clear, I think, as the diff-pipe-to-apply sequence, which is why I illustrated it that way.)